# how to get preceding-sibling value when i have name space on the root elements?

Tags: xml, xslt

In my previous question
[how to get preceding-sibling value when i have name space on the root elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28436461/how-to-get-preceding-sibling-value-when-i-have-name-space-on-the-root-elements)
I am getting partial result but I am looking for other conditions which is  "there is no start for this guid so activity name will be empty"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [implementing lookup in XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28666340/implementing-lookup-in-xslt/28666689#28666689) I believe what you need is ...

Try adding this to the top level of your stylesheet:

```
<xsl:key name="start" match="te:E2ETraceEvent[s:System/s:SubType/@Name='Start']" use="s:System/s:Correlation/@ActivityID" />
```

and then add this column to your table:

```
<td>
    <xsl:value-of select="key('start', s:System/s:Correlation/@ActivityID)/te:ApplicationData"/>    
</td>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, It is working great as I expected. Really appreciated!!!