# implementing lookup in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Running [xml](/questions/tagged/xml) and [xslt](/questions/tagged/xslt) below and getting the output at bottom.  Column with *black background* **Activity Correct Name** added manually to provide desired output of **Activity Name** column which produces wrong values at this moment.  I would like to implement following logic.

> Pseudo;
>
> - **Select** records **where** *Level*==Start
>
>   - **Set** *ActivityName* = *Description*
>   - **Capture** *ActivityId* and *ActivityName* into memory for future lookup
> - **Set** each record's ActivityName based on Captured records where *ActivityId* is a match

*you may also find completed logic with C# at [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FEw4QQ)*

## XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl" ?>
<root>
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
   <System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
        <SubType Name="Information">0</SubType>
        <Correlation ActivityID="a54221e2-ad37-434a-8f0d-101f7abc2221" />
    </System>
    <ApplicationData>Test21</ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
   <System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
        <SubType Name="Information">0</SubType>
        <Correlation ActivityID="d30741c2-da73-434a-8f0d-101f7ceb2228" />
    </System>
    <ApplicationData>Test24</ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
    <System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
        <SubType Name="Start">0</SubType>
        <Correlation ActivityID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" />
    </System>
    <ApplicationData>Alpha</ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
    <System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
        <SubType Name="Information">0</SubType>
        <Correlation ActivityID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" />
    </System>
    <ApplicationData>Test31</ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
    <System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
        <SubType Name="Verbose">0</SubType>
        <Correlation ActivityID="3b081a36-43d5-4ecc-b381-628c33316205" />
    </System>
    <ApplicationData>Test51</ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
    <System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
        <SubType Name="Start">0</SubType>
        <Correlation ActivityID="aa5a5b9c-4b24-43af-9f49-32656385e17d" />
    </System>
    <ApplicationData>Bravo</ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
   <System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
        <SubType Name="Start">0</SubType>
        <Correlation ActivityID="d30741c2-da73-434a-8f0d-101f7ceb2228" />
    </System>
    <ApplicationData>Charlie</ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
    <System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
        <SubType Name="Error">0</SubType>
        <Correlation ActivityID="aa5a5b9c-4b24-43af-9f49-32656385e17d" />
    </System>
    <ApplicationData>Test71</ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
   <System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
        <SubType Name="Transfer">0</SubType>
        <Correlation ActivityID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" />
    </System>
    <ApplicationData>Test41</ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>    
</root>
```

## XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:te="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"
                xmlns:s="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"
                xmlns:sd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/08/System.Diagnostics"
                xmlns:tr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord"
                exclude-result-prefixes="te s sd tr">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>                  
            </head>
            <body>
                <div>
                    <div>
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>                                
                                <th>Description</th>
                                <th>Level</th>
                                <th>Activity Name</th>
                                <th>Activity ID</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>                     
                            <xsl:for-each select="//te:E2ETraceEvent">

                            <xsl:variable name="level">
                                <xsl:value-of select=".//s:SubType/@Name"/>
                            </xsl:variable>

                            <xsl:variable name="description">
                                <xsl:value-of select=".//te:ApplicationData/text()"/>
                            </xsl:variable>

                            <tr>
                                <!-- APPLICATION DATA -->
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="$description"/>
                                </td>

                                <!-- LEVEL -->
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="$level"/>                                     
                                </td>

                                <!-- ACTIVITY NAME -->
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="((. | preceding-sibling::te:E2ETraceEvent)[s:System/s:SubType/@Name='Start'])[last()]/te:ApplicationData"/>
                                </td>

                                <!-- ACTIVITY ID -->
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select=".//s:Correlation/@ActivityID"/>                                       
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

## OUTPUT

[image: result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pseudocode is a bit cryptic (like there no *records where Level==Start*). Besides, XSLT doesn't work that way. In XSLT, a lookup is accomplished using a [key](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#key).

Try adding this to the top level of your stylesheet:

```
<xsl:key name="start" match="te:E2ETraceEvent[s:System/s:SubType/@Name='Start']" use="s:System/s:Correlation/@ActivityID" />
```

and then add this column to your table:

```
<td>
    <xsl:value-of select="key('start', s:System/s:Correlation/@ActivityID)/te:ApplicationData"/>    
</td>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by "there no records where Level==Start" I have 3 of that [here](http://i.imgur.com/wXV3xIa.png).  Anyway, I do appreciate for your time and attention.  It worked like a charm.  Thank you!

Comment: I mean there is no property named "Level" in your input. $level is something you have defined on the output side - but you can't use that to identify nodes in the original input.

Comment: Ohh, I got it.  My bad, since I already implemented _$level_ in XSLT, I referenced that one to make it easy. But you are right, I should also state that. Thx.